# Education Tax Return in US

Tags: united-states, taxes, education, refund

I've just stubmled upon a website: https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/calculators/taxcaster/

I entered my one year tuition fee (~$12k) and its showing: **Your Refund - $1000**

Background: I'm an international student and have a valid SSN.

How can I get the refund? :)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're an international student on J/F visa or are claiming a treaty position - then you're probably not eligible for these benefits. These education credits are only available on the US Resident tax returns.